# Trying to find words in a separate text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, file, sockets

I'm currently trying to figure out how to find a word in a separate text file.

---

I'm using `Python 3.x` and I'm trying to make a server and client thread and the client is supposed to input a word.
The server then is supposed to find the word in the list given to me that's in a txt file.

---

How would I go about searching for the word in the file?
Should I import it with a header or is there a different approach I should use?

Comment: You could open the file (using `open`) and store it in a string or run a grep command. Are you just trying to see if the word is in a text file? Or do you have several files

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
with open(r"C:\Path\to\file.txt", 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
if ("my word" in content):
    print("Your string is in the file")
else:
    print("String not found")
```

#### Explaination

---

The [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) built-in function is used like this:

```
file = open(r"C:\\Your\path\{file_name}.{file_extension}", mode_for_opening_the_file)
```

The default mode is `'r'`, which means you are going to read the file.

---

You can handle a file in more ways, the two most used of which are:

1. The `with` keyword
2. The simple assignation of the file object to a variable

First example:

```
with open(r"MyFile.json", 'r') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Second example:

```
file = open(r"MyFile.json", 'w+')
file.write("Hello World")
file.close() # The with method automatically close the file, saving all the changes
```

#### Some more information

---

If you want more information about opening files with python, check this:

- [Reading and Writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files)
- [Write to an existing file](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)
- [Reading text files](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/)